# Native module cannot be null is happened from?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I pull the last changes from git in my react-native project, when I run the application the process in XCode finished without errors, but when the application is opened gave me this error: "Native module cannot be null".
I have seen many issues in git and the configuration of Libraries is fine, I don't know where is came from this error.
If somebody has encountered this kind of error, please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing the same issue from yesterday have you find any solution?